# Opening Google Maps with 'a href' Location

Tags: php, html, google-maps, web

In olx.in, you can browse Ads and click on the Ad Location. If someone clicks one Ad Location, the Google Maps will be opened in the small screen on the current tab, In smartphones, the Google Maps App will be opened. What is the logic behind this?

How to show the location in Google Maps while clicking on the Ad Location?

In OLX.in, users have to select Location for their Ads when posting an Ad. This Location is seeing in Google Maps while others browse the Ads. Therefore the owner of the Ad no need to  embed Google Map location code directly inside 'a href'.

How to open Google Maps Window in current tab like Olx.in when clicking on Ad Location?

Comment: `<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=1200 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, District of Columbia, 20003">...</a>`

Answer (score 2):

### Url:

https://www.google.fr/maps/place/YOUR+ADRESSE +HERE

### Example :

```
<a 
href="https://www.google.fr/maps/place/7+Impasse+de+l'Épi,+84000+Avignon" > adresse  to .....</a>
```

Comment: Yes, when clicked google map will automaticallt oppened

Comment: In OLX.in, users have to select Location for their Ads. This Location is seeing in Google Maps. Therefore We Can't write location code directly inside 'a href' ??

Comment: Works very well thanks! Worked for me in Chrome and Safari on a iPhone